# PyPika how to generate IF statement

Tags: pypika

How do I generate an IF statement in PyPika?

I am trying to generate a BigQuery query that pivots a row to a column. I found that if I use the following in a query (where date_range is from a WITH statement):

```
IF (date_range.kind = 'year', date_range.name, NULL) as year
```

then this will work. However, I haven't found a way to generate this SQL fragment in PyPika.

For completeness, this is an example of a query I need to run in BigQuery:

```
WITH date_range AS (
SELECT
    CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM year) as string) name,
    'year' kind,
    year start_date,
    DATE_ADD(year, INTERVAL 1 year) end_date
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2010-01-01','2020-06-01',INTERVAL 1 year)) year

UNION ALL

SELECT
    FORMAT_DATE('%B', month)||' '||EXTRACT(year FROM month) name,
    'month' kind,
    month start_date,
    DATE_ADD(month,INTERVAL 1 month) end_date
FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2010-01-01','2020-06-01',INTERVAL 1 month)) month
)
SELECT
IF(date_range.kind='year', date_range.name, null) as year,
IF(date_range.kind='month', date_range.name, null) as month,
SUM(sales.sales_value) sales_value,
FROM sales
JOIN date_range ON sales.start_date>=date_range.start_date AND sales.end_date<date_range.end_date
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month
```

The more general question I have is, is there a way to pass literal strings to PyPika so that those will be included in the resulting query string? There are several SQL fragments that Pypika does not generate (such as `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` and `UNNEST`, at least as far I can find) and passing the actual SQL fragment to PyPika would solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it applies but be sure to also check whether the CASE statement can help you.

Other than that you can either subclass PyPika's Function class and overwrite `get_sql` and use that or (ab)use the `CustomFunction` and `PseudoColumn` utility classes like this:

```
from pypika import CustomFunction

sales_table = Table('sales')
MyIf = CustomFunction('IF', ['condition', 'if', 'else'])
q = Query.from_(sales_table).select(
    MyIf(PseudoColumn("date_range.kind = 'year'"), PseudoColumn("date_range.name"), None, alias="year")
)
```

However, I'd probably recommend making a ticket on the PyPika Github.

Note: I wasn't able to test this.

Comment: I ended up using the `CustomFunction`. Thanks for your help!